# How do you break out of while loop by pressing a gamepad button (User Input)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, while-loop, pygame, scheduled-tasks

I am using pygame just so that I can use the xbox controller on my script. My goal is to press a button to start a repeating task, and then be able to press another button to break out of the repeating task. I should then be able to press the original button to resume the task.

Before I even post the code, I know the crux of my problem is this part here: (something wrong with my indentation but the code works).

```
while True:
                            schedule.run_pending()
                            time.sleep(1)
```

How do I break out of this while loop so that I can use the next button `JOYHATMOTION:` Basically I would be using `JOYHATMOTION` to pause the `job` function.

Here is the code. It prints "Hello World" every five seconds for 200 seconds.

```
import schedule
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
import time
import sys

import pygame

from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


def job():
    print('Hello World')


pygame.joystick.init()
joysticks = [pygame.joystick.Joystick(i) for i in range(pygame.joystick.get_count())]
for joystick in joysticks:
    print(joystick.get_name())

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)
            if event.button == 8:

                schedule.every(5).seconds.until(timedelta(seconds=200)).do(job)

                while True:
                            schedule.run_pending()
                            time.sleep(1)

        if event.type == JOYHATMOTION:
            if event.value[0] == 1:
                print(event)
                

            if event.value[0] == -1:
                print(event)

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
```

I have tried:

```
while True:
                if event.type == JOYHATMOTION:
                    if event.value[0] == 1:
                        break
                    else: 
                           schedule.run_pending()
                           time.sleep(1)
```

but this dosent seem to work. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never try to control the application with a loop inside the application loop. Use the application loop. The application loop is continuously executed. Use a `game_state` variable that indicates the current state of the application. Execute the code in the application depending on the state of the variable.
With this approach, you can easily change the state back when another key is pressed.

```py
game_state = ""
run = True

while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           run = False 
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                run = False 

        if event.type == JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print(event)
            
            if event.button == 8:
                if game_state == "schedule":
                    game_state = ""          # schedule off
                else:
                    game_state = "schedule"  # schedule on
                    schedule.every(5).seconds.until(timedelta(seconds=200)).do(job)

        if event.type == JOYHATMOTION:
            if event.value[0] == 1:
                print(event)
            if event.value[0] == -1:
                print(event)

    if game_state == "schedule":
        schedule.run_pending()

    # [...]

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Thank You so much. A little bit above my head so I am going to try to incorporate this to my code. I will report back :)